# Add padding to a TextField Compose cursor position

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, textfield

I want to add an extra 32 dp padding to a cursor position in Textfield Composable, I tried using TextFieldValue and updating the TextRange property but it didn't work.

```
 var textFieldValueState by remember {
        mutableStateOf(
            TextFieldValue(
                text = "hello",
                selection = TextRange(32.dp) 
            )
        )
    }
```

```
OutlinedTextField(
    value = textFieldValueState,
    onValueChange = { textFieldValueState = it },
    ...
    )
```

Comment: Padding at the start of the text field or for any entry of text? Provide a screenshot or prototype.

Answer (score 0):

you should use textIndent at textstyle, not only for first line, but for next paragraphs you can set different paddings, pay attenition we assume you want to make 32 dp padding:

```
OutlinedTextField(
textStyle = TextStyle( 
textIndent = TextIndent(30.sp)))
```

also for other lines :

```
    OutlinedTextField(
textStyle = TextStyle(
    textIndent = TextIndent(firstLine = 30.sp, restLine =32.sp)))
```